# Why my sister inherited the half of empire?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I was an emperor of Britannia and a dozen kingdoms. The inheritance low was "[Agnatic-Cognatic Primogeniture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIxGI.jpg)" (screenshot was taken after the emperor died).

When my Ruler died, he had two daughters. One was [the heir and inherited half of the empire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBup4.jpg).

Somehow the second got literally the half of my kingdoms, [including the duchy with the capital](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUSex.jpg).

### Question #1

Luckily she is still my vassal, but how did she get the half where the inheritance law was primogeniture?

### Question #2

I guess I can cause her to revolt and revoke all kingdoms and the duchy, but I'm afraid counties' revocation may cause a lot of unrest.

What is the best way to get back kingdoms and my main duchy (Mercia, if it makes any difference)?

Answer (score 6):

When a character dies, then all their titles get distributed according to the inheritance laws which apply to each title. Kingdoms within an empire do not necessarily have the same succession laws. It is possible that some of the kingdoms had agnatic-cognatic gravelkind or elective succession and thus went to the younger daughter.

Regarding getting those kingdoms back: Check the lines of succession of the kingdoms. If you murder her and her two children, then the kingdoms should go back to you. If murder is not a viable option, then it might become quite difficult to get those titles back into your demesne. Honestly, the easiest way to unify that empire could be to eradicate *your* branch of the family so she becomes your heir and then die so you continue playing as her. In order to do that you need to make sure that your two sons die childless and that your husband doesn't knock you up again.

Comment: It looks like the Empress has a bunch of strong claims on the kingdoms since she was one of the top three in the line of succession.  I believe if revocation is allowed you can revoke titles that you have a claim on without penalty (although you may not be able to revoke all of them).

Comment: @IllusiveBrian I think you mixed up the two screenshots. The one with all the strong claims is the younger sister. The empress only has three weak claims on some duchies.

Comment: Oh, no, I just haven't played with the new UI layout and read the owned titles as claims.  The succession on all the owned titles could also be changed to seniority, although it would be hard to do with that many titles and would require luck to be able to then change it on the other kingdom titles once the player is playing their ruler again.  Honestly, trying to hold a lot of titles personally isn't a viable long term strategy.

Comment: I could assume that one of Kingdoms could have the inheritance laws different from what I expect (if I miss something), but I did double check them periodically and made sure all are primogeniture. Can't understand how half of kingdoms could be missing... :(
Thanks for ideas.